# PHP Form Sending Issues (using SendInBlue)

Tags: php, forms, sendinblue

I have a basic PHP contact form which I use on a couple of sites, which sends email using the [SendInBlue](http://sendinblue.com) API.

My problem is that I have the form working perfectly on 1 site, now I am using the EXACT same code for a second site and just changing the email, name, etc - however when testing it I now get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mailin::send_email() in
>   /URL/contactpage.php on line 71

FYI, line 71 is:

> $mailin->send_email($data);

I have attached the complete code below - this works perfectly on 1 site, but I get this error on my second site.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

```
<?php

//Email Details for Form Notifications
$email_to =   'Test@test.com'; //the address to which the email will be sent 
$email_to_name     =  'Test';

//Form Fields
$fname     =   $_POST['firstname'];
$lname     =   $_POST['lastname'];
$email    =   $_POST['email'];
$fullmessage    =   $_POST['message'];

//Subject Lines
$subject_to  =   'Test';
$subject_touser  =   'Test';

//URL Redirects
$confirm  =   'TestConfirm';
$errorurl  =    'TestError';

//Validate
$emailval = filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
if ($emailval == false)
{
    header("Location: $errorurl");
} else {

    // The email to us
    $message_to = 'Message here';
    //

    // The email to them
    $message_touser = 'Message here';
    //

    require('Mailin.php');

    //Notification Email
    $mailin = new Mailin('https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0','MY_KEY');
    $data = array( "to" => array($email_to=>$email_to_name),
                "cc" => array($email_to_cc=>$email_to_cc_name),
                "from" => array($email,$fname),
                "subject" => $subject_to,
                "html" => $message_to
    );

    $mailin->send_email($data);

    //Email to User
    $mailin = new Mailin('https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0','MY_KEY');
    $data2 = array( "to" => array($email=>$fname),
                "from" => array($email_to,$email_to_name),
                "subject" => $subject_touser,
                "html" => $message_touser
    );

    $mailin->send_email($data2);  

    header("Location: $confirm");

}
```

?>

Comment: So I have discovered that this code works PERFECTLY on one domain, but on a separate URL on the same domain it returns the error... So the code works, but it doesn't want to exist in certain places. All required files are exactly the same...

Answer (score 0):

I was using a deprecated Mailin.php. Updated the file and everything works now.